# Parsing a HTML element

Tags: php, dom, html-parsing

I've used DOM before to parse websites in PHP.

I know I should never try to parse HTML using regex.

But... (I don't want to start a shitstorm, just an answer :P )

If i want to parse just 1 HTML element, e.g.

```
<a href="http://example.com/something?id=1212132131133&filter=true" rel="blebeleble" target="_blank">
```

And find the content of the `href` attribute, can I (and probably I need to if I can) use DOM to parse this string or do I need a complete webpage to be able to parse it using the DOM?

Comment: What does parsing using the DOM mean?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can do this.

You have to:

- pretend that the `<a />` tag constitutes the whole document;
- ensure that you close the tag;
- ensure that the input string is valid XML (note that I've replaced your `&` with `&amp;`, the proper HTML entity).

Code:

```
<?php
$str = '<a href="http://example.com/something?id=1212132131133&amp;filter=true" rel="blebeleble" target="_blank" />';

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadXML($str);
var_dump($dom->childNodes->item(0)->attributes->getNamedItem('href')->value);

// Output: string(57) "http://example.com/something?id=1212132131133&filter=true"
?>
```

---

PS, if you want to include the link text, that's ok too:

```
$str = '<a href="http://example.com/something?id=1212132131133&amp;filter=true" rel="blebeleble" target="_blank">Click here!</a>';
// .. code .. //

// Output: string(57) "http://example.com/something?id=1212132131133&filter=true"
```

Comment: Great answer, thanks a bunch for this. I have no problem with Beautiful Soup or Nokogiri, but I find DomDocument difficult to use.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily adapt a regex to parse just this tag, given you've isolated it. An example can be [found here](http://www.mkyong.com/regular-expressions/how-to-extract-html-links-with-regular-expression/). It's for java, so remember to change the case insensitive modifier to the end!